# How do I query based on a truncated primary key value?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables; one table contains all of my orders (ORDERS), and the other is a list of cities (CITY).

The first 6 digits of the OrderID for any given order is generated based on the city from which the order originated.

The CITY table simply has a six digit code in the left column, and the name of the city on the right.

What I would like to do is create a query that will allow me to pull the city name by comparing the first 6 digits of the OrderID with the CITY table.

Example:

ORDER

```
OrderID               Customer Name               Date
11111135465           David Summerhill            09/28/2011
44444435463           Margaret Jefferson          06/17/2013
55555548635           Matthew Cunningham          07/07/2012
22222265437           David Summerhill            07/08/2013
```

CITY

```
ID          City Name
111111      New York
222222      Detroit
333333      San Jose
444444      Houston
555555      Seattle
666666      Phoenix
```

Result:

```
Customer Name               Date                   City
David Summerhill            09/28/2011             New York
Margaret Jefferson          06/17/2013             Houston
Matthew Cunningham          07/07/2012             Seattle
David Summerhill            07/08/2013             New York
```

Although I am using MS Access, I would like to know how to do this with standard SQL, preferably.

Comment: Can you alter the schema - the best thing to do is split the OrderID into two fields one for the city then it is a simple join on city

Comment: That's what I ended up doing as a quick fix, but that won't allow me to fix the problem on-the-fly.  Instead I would need to do periodic updates.  I don't have access to how the program codes the IDs.

Comment: It is not a quick fix but the long term one - coding fields that embed a meaning is just poor design - fixes that involve the splitting of the field are the short term hacks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LEFT()` in your `JOIN` if the City ID is a string:

```
SELECT [Customer Name], Date, [City Name]
FROM ORDER
JOIN CITY
 ON LEFT(OrderID,6) = City.ID
```

If the City code is an integer use one of the other responses.

Comment: Why should I use one of the others if I'm using BIGINT?  This seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I would either opt to use a computed column for the state to make an actually foreign key reference, or I would use a sargable predicate. When you use a function on the column of a predicate it can limit index seeks.

Something like this should work for you.

```
SELECT 
    O.CustomerName,
    [Date]= CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),O.Date,101),
    c.CityName
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Cities c 
    ON o.OrderID LIKE CAST(c.ID AS CHAR(6)) + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Customer_Name, Date, City
FROM Order
JOIN City
ON City.ID = OrderID DIV 100000
```